# Loading a separate set of .css and .js files based on current browser

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, browser, safari

I need to load a separate set of .css and .js files when on Firefox and a different set on Safari. How is this done?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Google seems to [have a lot of results](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=browser+detection) for you. By the way, what if the user has IE or Chrome?

Comment: It's probably important to ask *why* you need to do this. If you have compatibility issues, this is never the best way to handle them.

Comment: Hi nnnnnn, doing this completely in JavaScript does work. I was wondering if there is something like conditional comments that I can do in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this website.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Comment: Yep, this pretty covers it. And as nnnnnn said, this should have been easily google-able.

Comment: Is there something like conditional comments that I can do in HTML?

Something like: <!--[if IE]>